# For Loop validating dates VB

Tags: sql, for-loop, select, vb6

I have a legacy vb6 application where user enters txtFrom and txtTo dates. I have to run a query to SQL SERVER to tblA where there are records with FROM and TO dates to count how many records they are. How would I run a loop taking each date between txtFrom and txtTo to count the # of records that exist for that date in the tblA

```
RecNo            FromDate          ToDate
1                8/11/2016         8/21/2016
2                8/13/2016         8/23/2016
```

So basically I want to do something like this

```
For each day between txtFrom and txtTo

Select RecNo from tblA where txtDate is between FromDate and Todate
if recordcount >5 then
   msgbox "Too many"
End if

Next date
```

Now I have a good idea how to do the SQL part of it, i'm just not sure how to loop through the dates so that I can use them to check the record count.

Maybe do DateDiff then do a For x = 1 to Datediff and then do dateadd for eachdate

Comment: You don't need a loop for this.  You can do it in a single query.

Comment: How would I do that???

Comment: @davidccram very helpful!!!

Comment: In your SQL use `Count(RecNum) as NumRecs` to eliminate returning a big recordset and having to use `.MoveLast` and `.RecordCount`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer, here's how i did it....

```
Date3 = format(txtfrom,"mm/dd/yyyy")
For x = 0 to datediff("d",txtFrom,txtto)
    select RecNo from tblA where date3 between tblA.FromDate and tblA.ToDate
    rs.open <--- check my record count if everything good then
    Date3 = dateadd("d",1,Date3)

next
```

Comment: Still looks like pseudo code to me. You're going to need rs.movelast before getting a valid record count.

Comment: @dbmitch - but i ran it this way. Basically before the loop starts, i set it to FROM date, then move through the loop until it gets to the count of DATEDIFF  - so if i put in 8/15/2016 for FROM and 8/20/2016 for TO, the loop is for x = 0 to 5 and at the end of it, it just exits the loop. Seems to work fine. How would I use rs.movelast in this loop?

Answer (score 1):

Refer the below urls for how to Navigate a recordset:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj249822.aspx
>
> http://allenbrowne.com/func-ado.html